# Am I wrong, or is {labels} *not* about the \label command?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Taking a glance at the 42 questions tagged with [labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labels) at the moment, it seems that they are a weird mixture of questions about labels in diagrams etc. and about the `\label` command used for cross-referencing. I propose to embrace the following definition of [labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labels) as tag wiki excerpt (and to retag questions to [cross-referencing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-referencing) when appropriate):

> {labels} is about customizing the
>   labels of diagrams and mathematical
>   constructs like matrices. If your
>   question is about \label or similar
>   commands, use {cross-referencing}
>   instead.

Comment: In that case I am for renaming to {diagram-lables}. Otherwise I will get misused.

Comment: @Caramdir: Renaming seems like a good idea, but is there any term that would also cover mathematical constructs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with that tag wiki entry. I also support adding [cross-referencing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-referencing) to questions regarding the `\label` command which dont't have that tag yet or replacing the [labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labels) tag on such questions.

I think [labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labels) is a good filtering tag supporting general tags such as [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf), [diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diagrams) and [matrices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrices), but not as single tag for cross-referencing. If a question is really specifically about the labels in cross-referencing, it may have the tag, why not - but it should not miss the [cross-referencing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-referencing) tag.